# Integrating TinyMCE WYSIWYG HTML Editor to React Native apps

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, tinymce, wysiwyg

I am trying to incorporate TinyMCE WYSIWYG HTML Editor into a react native WebView Component. Is there a way to perform this task?

Answer (score 5):

I added Tinymce WYSIWYG editor inside react-native WebView component.My Webview Component looks like this:

```
<WebView
 source={require("./WebView.html")}
 style={{width: Dwidth, height: Dheight}}
 onMessage={(event)=>{
 const x= event.nativeEvent.data;
 console.log("x: ",x);
 console.log("Type is: ",typeof(x));
 }}
/>
```

The corresponding WebView.html file:

```
<head>
<style>
    body {
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>
<script src="./tinymce.full.js?apiKey=<API_KEY>">

</script>

<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#mytextarea'
    });

    function manipulateForm() {
        var textContent = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({format: 'raw'});
        manipulateFormNew(textContent);
    }

    function manipulateFormNew(textContent) {
        alert(textContent);
        window.postMessage(textContent);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="myForm" onSubmit="return manipulateForm()" method="post">
  <textarea id="mytextarea">Please Share your thoughts here</textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="submit__button" value="Post Your Thoughts">
 </form>
</body>
```

Here the tinymce.full.js file contains the Tinymce JavaScript code. Same directory also contains other Tinymce resources like skins, themes, style, etc files.